# Why Is A Period Used To Call "toString()" On a number JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when toString is called on a number it isn't called like a typical function. I would expect `var num = 5; toString(num);` but instead it is done like `var num = 5; num.toString();`. Why is a period used to call the function on the number rather than supplying the number as an argument? I know that periods are used to reference properties of an object but I can't see how that applies to this situation. Sorry if this is an easy question, but I am new to programming and I really want to understand the language before I continue.

Comment: [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) is a *method* defined on `Number.protype`. As an aside, `5..toString()` also works. As does `(5).toString()`.

Comment: `toString()` on it's own is actually `window.toString()` which is [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). It does not take any arguments

Comment: In simplest but not quite accurate terms: Because Javascript is an object oriented language. You have objects and these objects have methods which you can call. For example a number object has the `toString()` method which returns a new string object which is the string representation of that number. What you expected is how Functional languages would work, in these you have a clear distinction between data structures and functions that transform those data structures. The concept of classes and objects doesn't exist in them like it does in object oriented languages.

Comment: For a beginner this difference might seem difficult to grasp or distinguish but it is a quite fundamental one.

Comment: @XaverKapeller You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `.` is used to access a property on an object. In this case, a Number has a property on it `toString` that is a function you can invoke.

```
var num = 5;
num.toString //function toString() { [native code] }
num.toString() //"5"
```

the function `toString` without anything preceding it is really a property on the `window` object, and is the equivalent of the following:

```
window.toString //function toString() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` on it's own is actually `window.toString()` which is [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

It does not take any arguments.

```js
console.info(toString === window.toString)
console.info(window.toString())
```

What you may perceive as *global*, built-in functions are actually methods of the [`window` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Comment: OK, but I think maybe the OP wants to know in terms of language design why there isn't a function that you can call in the form `formatNumber(someNumber)` instead of calling it as a method.

Comment: @nnnnnn I added some extra info about `window`

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of the number is defined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString.

If you use directly the toString, this means that you ask from the global scope to use the global toString ( window.toString()). The window is very generic to know how to convert a specific number to String.